# Spring MVC Redirects with Spring Cloud Eureka

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

When using Spring MVC and Spring Cloud Eureka, how can I get Spring MVC to resolve my redirect URLs similar to how RestTemplate is able to?

For example, if I have two services, user-service and movie-service that are both registered with Spring Cloud Eureka, how can I get a controller in user-service to redirect to a movie-service endpoint, without hard coding the url?

```
@Controller
public class UserServiceController {
    @PostMapping("/something")
    public String performSomeAction() {
        // I'd like movie service to be resolved to an instance that is registered with Eureka
        return "redirect:http://movie-service/some-url
    }
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? I know Spring cloud is normally used with APIs, but to me it seems like it would make sense to be able to integrate your web applications with it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Controller
public class UserServiceController {
    @Autowired
    LoadBalancerClient loadBalancerClient;

    @PostMapping("/something")
    public String performSomeAction() {
        ServiceInstance serviceInstance = loadBalancerClient.choose("movie-service");
        if (serviceInstance != null) {
            return "redirect:http://"+ serviceInstance.getHost() + ":" + serviceInstance.getPort() +"/some-url
        }
        // throw an error or something else
    }
}
```